# google line chart lineWidth is getting thin

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

Im using google line chart for my application, in my chart for first two points the lineWidth is thick and for **last two points the lineWidth is very thin**. How can i over come this problem, i need to draw a graph with same lineWidth throughout the chart. And when i click over the point the pointSize is enlarged, **i dont want to enlarge the pointSize even when the mouse click**.

[image]

Comment: The line width problem you are having is quite odd; could you post code that reproduces the problem?  As far as the point size goes, you can set the starting point size (via the `pointSize` option), but you cannot change the highlight effect on hover or click without disabling interactivity entirely (which gets rid of the tooltips).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set minValue of the hAxis to -1 to the lowest data point of the chart